# Second difficulty in understanding the proof of theorem 1.14 in Hungerford.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, proof-explanation

The theorem and part of its proof is given in the following pictures:

[image]

[image]

But I do not know why the author divide the proof of the first implication into these 2 steps: (1) when $A=A_1 \oplus\cdots\oplus A_n$ and when (2) $A \cong A_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus A_n$, could anyone explain this for me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ease of understanding. It is clearer what happens in the case $A = A_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus A_n$, so that gets explained first. Then the slight generalization $A \cong A_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus A_n$ via the isomorphism $f$ is discussed; the special case is recovered when $f = \mathrm{id}_A$.